# How to list contract-to-hire conversion on resume/LinkedIn when looking for new jobs

Tags: resume, work-experience, linkedin, contractors

**Background**
I am an interactive designer that was in a contract-to-hire position (at one company, “Company A”) for exactly 1 year with an outside contracting agency. I’ve recently been converted to an official salaried employee with Company A for a little over a month now. I am currently looking for new opportunities outside of Company A that will challenge me more, but I’m being very selective about my next move as Company A is generally a good place to work with a positive reputation.

I haven’t updated my resume/LinkedIn profile to reflect my new job status at Company A, as I’m confused where to go from here and what will look best in my current situation. Right now, my description on my resume/LinkedIn profile for this job looks like this:

```
“Contracting Agency”
June 2016–present 
Contractor

    Interactive Designer (“Company A”)
    June 2016–present

(job description)
```

**Problem**
How do I list my experience on my resume/LinkedIn since converting to salaried employee when looking for new jobs? I don’t want to look like a job hopper by listing both the contracting agency and Company A as separate roles (especially if I am only a salaried employee at Company A for a short time).

Should I keep my resume/LinkedIn profile as-is to make it look like I’m still a contractor? Should I update them and replace the contracting agency’s name with Company A’s name so that it appears I’ve been working there for at least a year? Or should I do something else?

Comment: I'm not sure indicating your employer as the contracting agency is helpful to your resume or to its readers. I would list the client companies and then mention them as contracts. If asked during the interview process or what-have-you, then you should mention the contracting agency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I always did it is like this

XYZ Corporation.  Jan, 2004-May2006(contract) May 2006 - Present(full time)